# Any jdk library giving me error in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, java-11

Hello when trying to do docker-compose of JDK in order to run a java application I always get the same error. I tried a lot of tags and all of them result in the same.

```
 => ERROR FROM docker.io/library/build:latest                              2.5s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/build:latest                              2.5s
 => CANCELED [stage-1 1/2] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi@sha2  2.4srequire authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
 => => resolve docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi@sha256:e019d29e3480ae  0.0s
```

The error is not specific.

My docker file is the following

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 as builder
COPY app /home/app/src
COPY app/pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/LineServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/app/LineServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/home/app/LineServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?